# Image not being displayed in tkinter python

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I've been using tkinter for a while now and currently I am working on an app in which I need to display an image at the home screen. The problem is that though the code is fine, the image is not being displayed. This is the image:
[image]

This the code I am using. Please tell the problem:

```
    from tkinter import *
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("1000x700")
    root.minsize(1000, 700)
    root.maxsize(1000, 700)
    
    bg_img = Label(image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("image_processing20200410-19194-aihwb4.png")), compound=CENTER)
    bg_img.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
```

I have tried using the grid geometry manager but it is not working. Please help

Comment: It is because there is no variable references the image, so it will be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a PhotoImage to a Tkinter widget, you have to keep a separate reference to the image object. Otherwise, the image will not show up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define image object separately and then load it into `Label`:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1000x700")
root.resizable(False, False)
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("image_processing20200410-19194-aihwb4.png"))
panel = Label(root, image=image)
panel.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
root.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this code it might work

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ImageTk import PhotoImage
    
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1000x700")
root.minsize(1000, 700)
root.maxsize(1000, 700)
    
bg_img = Label(image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Jitn6.png")), compound=CENTER)
bg_img.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do it like this

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1000x700")
root.minsize(1000, 700)
root.maxsize(1000, 700)
my_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("image_processing20200410-19194-aihwb4.png"))
bg_img = Label(image=my_image, compound=CENTER)
bg_img.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
```

you should first put the image in a variable then pass it in